# Story with people from another world who rely on some technology/machine which feeds them with an artificial sense of reality

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read this English young adult fiction book 5-6 years ago. This has probably a been brought out **after 2000**.

All I remember is that the main character-a boy visits **a place where people are in some kind of induced-dream state**. The "dream-world" offers them things that are not achievable in the real world. The caretaker of the place tells the protagonist that people prefer to be in that world rather than the real one.

Also I remember mentions of there being **more than one sun** .In another book of the same series,the main character gets treated to wellness in a tribal house-a girl tends to him there.There also is a contest of some sort in one of the books,the protagonist is the youngest person in it and yet he wins(something conducted for the entertainment of some other people).

Comment: Please look through the questions on https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see how many you can edit answers to in your question. As it is, we don't have many details to work from.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/243568/series-where-the-protagonist-jumps-through-portals-to-stop-someone-messing-up-th (about the series as a whole)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Expanding from my comment)

I think this might be a conflation of a couple of books from the Pendragon series by D.J. Machale. Books came out between 2002 and 2009. They're about a boy named Bobby Pendragon who travels to various territories (realities). The main one you're mentioning would be *The Reality Bug*.

[image]

From the Wikipedia summary:

> Aja explains that Lifelight is a virtual reality world—a computer that
>   gives people's desires the appearance of being real. Almost everyone
>   on Veelox is in it, living out their own perfect virtual lives. ...
>   Aja then explains that, because Lifelight is so perfect, hardly anyone
>   leaves. No food is being made. The territory is dying.

The contest book would be *The Quillan Games*:

> The story takes place on a territory called Quillan, in the city of
>   Rune, whose population live dreary lives under the rule of the
>   megacorporation 'Blok'. Many people gamble on the eponymous games in
>   hope of a better life; but may lose their lives, their families, or
>   their professions if the bet fails. The games' celebrity players are
>   called 'challengers', and often kill each other during the
>   competition. ... Upon arrival on Quillan, Bobby witnesses a fellow
>   Traveler die in the games; but is soon captured by the android 'dados'
>   of Quillan's police force, and recruited as a 'challenger' by the
>   siblings LaBerge and Veego. ... Ultimately, Bobby wins the game and
>   the support of the people, who revolt against Blok.

The tribal house healing book might be *The Rivers of Zadaa*, though it could also be a scene from a different book I've forgotten.

> This story takes place mainly on a territory called Zadaa. There will
>   be two main tribes here: The Rokador and the Batu. The Rokador live in
>   tunnels underground and are fair-skinned, while the Batu are
>   dark-skinned and live in a sunbathed city called Xhaxhu in the desert.
>   ... Soon afterwards, Saint Dane, who is disguised as a Batu warrior,
>   beats Bobby up with a wooden staff. Bobby is almost killed but is
>   rescued by Pelle a Zinj, the kind prince, and recovers quickly in a
>   Batu hospital.

I can't find a mention of the planet in The Reality Bug having more than one sun, but a different territory in the series does. Snippet below from the first book, The Merchant of Death:

> But it wasn't going to happen today. The suns were going down and it
>   was getting dark. Yeah, that's right. Suns. Plural. Remember when I
>   told you there were three suns? Well, they all set at the same time,
>   but in opposite parts of the sky.